# CentOS7: su /bin/bash: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: centos7, ulimit

Whenever I try to change to testuser, I get resource temporarily unavailable message. The nproc and nofile limits are set to 65k. testuser runs multiple java programs.
Did not exceed the nproc and nofile values(verified using ps and lsof commands) for testuser.

Contents of /etc/security/limits.conf

```
* soft     nproc          65535
* hard     nproc          65535
* soft     nofile         65535
* hard     nofile         65535
testuser   soft  nofile  65535
testuser   hard  nofile  65535
```

This is a CentOS 7 system running on a powerful Dell 64bit server.

What else could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on CentOS7.

Below is my `/etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf` file.

```
    *          soft    nproc     4096
    root       soft    nproc     unlimited
    jenkins     soft    nproc     65535
```

I had issue with Jenkins user - not allowing to switch to Jenkins. This [RedHat link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/30316) helped me, though the solution is for RHEL4/5/6 but it is worked for CentOS7.